# Some equal values in column A from a CSV file and need to copy values from other files that matches with that column in excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Here is the example:

**File1.csv** (already created)

```
Column A | Column B
  1      |   1
  6      |   3
 12      |   4
 18      |   5
```

**File2.csv** (already created)

```
Column A | Column C
  2      |   2
  6      |   4
 12      |   5
```

**File3.csv** (what I want to create)

```
Column A | Column B | Column C 
  6      |   3      |   4
 12      |   4      |   5
```

Observation: those CSV files are enormous ~1 million of rows but I think there is no problem with that (I hope so), they have only
exactly two columns like the example. "vlookup" has not worked for me and I can't see the solution!

Observation 2: i can put the columns from different files in the same sheet but i need to match with the first column of them anyway.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a macro here? That would be much more efficient on such a large file...

Comment: This might be a good place for an Inner Join of the first field.

Comment: I'd recommend using power query for a data set that large.

Comment: The blanket redacting of your sample data may be detrimental. I've run a sample test workbook using ADO to query itself (i.e. the same workbook) but the column names throw errors unless the spaces are removed from the CSV field names.

Comment: Join solved my problem! I've done it in linux terminal. Thanks, guy. One more question: there is a way of thinking in join with some interval like "if their columns A values difference are between 10, I can join them and put in the third file with the mean of column A"or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all records to same sheet in order not force excel to open file every time function evaluates
2. Use this function in a third table (range  $g$1:$h$1000) to match ColumnB values from table1 (range $a$1:$b$1000...) that have common ColumnA value with table1 columnA values (range  $d$1:$e$1000).

`=VLOOKUP(d1;$a$1:$b$1000;2;FALSE)`

Comment: it seems to be ok but the memory exhausted

Comment: A dirty solution is to work with sorting.
1) Add a third column FileId and number your sources 1, 2.
2) Put all records together and sort first by column A then by Column C.
3) In a fourth column add formula to check if cell above matches with cell behind and return the value with FileId=1              
4) Turn column 4 formulas to values So then you can sort first by column 4 to get all matches together.